# Ejabberd IOS client registration

Tags: php, ios, xmpp, ejabberd

Im already setup my ejabberd server on MACOSX.
I can register an user on the Control Panel, 
but i want to enable in-band registration on my IOS client,
so that any future buddy request, dont need aproval.
whats the best aproach to do that?
ANy solution in PHP?

Comment: using php would be by definition an out-of-band solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using an existing interface which would be called from your PHP page which in turn would execute ejabberd commands.

Check out http://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd_xmlrpc